# ORACLE SUBSTR number type

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that uses the following in a select statement

```
WHERE section_id=SUBSTR(:rId, 5, 6)
```

where rId is N00401E

Thus I am extracting the 5th and 6th characters, "01" from the rId.

The error I'm getting is ORA-01722: invalid number

The rId has a type number (2)

I've tried TO_NUMBER but this is not working. Can anyone help?

Comment: `SUBSTR` works on string data type and not on number. What is the content of `rId`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract characters 5 an 6 you should:

```
SUBSTR(:rId, 5, 2)
```

See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm).

Comment: Thank you - that works! (and makes sense now that I have seen the docs.)